# Deploy to Heroku failing during bundling of gems

Tags: heroku, deployment, rubygems

I am trying to deploy my app to Heroku but I am getting the following error:

> ```
>    Installing mini_portile (0.5.2)
>    Installing ntlm-http (0.1.1)
>    Installing webrobots (0.1.1)
>    Installing naturalsorter (0.2.2)
>    Using pg (0.17.0)
>    Using bundler (1.5.2)
>    Using raindrops (0.12.0)
>
>    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
>    /tmp/build_4fb17050-b89d-47de-afc2-a6442ad2c755/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
> ```
>
> extconf.rb
>          checking for ffi.h... no
>          checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include,/usr/include/ffi... no
>          checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
>          checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
>          checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
>          checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... no
>          creating extconf.h
>          creating Makefile
>
> ```
>    make "DESTDIR="
>    Configuring libffi
>    /tmp/build_4fb17050-b89d-47de-afc2-a6442ad2c755/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/libffi/configure:
> ```
>
> line 7774: conftest.c: No such file or directory
>          /tmp/build_4fb17050-b89d-47de-afc2-a6442ad2c755/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/libffi/configure:
>   line 1698: conftest.i: No such file or directory
>          sed: can't read conftest.c: No such file or directory
>          /tmp/build_4fb17050-b89d-47de-afc2-a6442ad2c755/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/libffi/configure:
>   line 7774: conftest.c: No such file or directory
>          /tmp/build_4fb17050-b89d-47de-afc2-a6442ad2c755/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/libffi/configure:
>   line 1698: conftest.i: No such file or directory
>          sed: can't read conftest.c: No such file or directory
>          configure: error: in `/tmp/build_4fb17050-b89d-47de-afc2-a6442ad2c755/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux':
>          configure: error: C preprocessor "gcc -E" fails sanity check
>          See`config.log' for more details
>          make: *** ["/tmp/build_4fb17050-b89d-47de-afc2-a6442ad2c755/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a]
>   Error 1
>
> ```
>    Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_4fb17050-b89d-47de-afc2-a6442ad2c755/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3
> ```
>
> for inspection.
>          Results logged to /tmp/build_4fb17050-b89d-47de-afc2-a6442ad2c755/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
>          Installing kgio (2.9.1)
>          Installing rdiscount (2.1.7)
>          Installing sass (3.3.0.rc.3)
>          An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
>          Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.9.3'` succeeds before bundling.  !  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.  !
>
> !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Is your local machine a Windows machine?

Comment: Good man. Pushed both *Gemfile* and *Gemfile.lock*?

Comment: Both committed and pushed

Comment: *Gemfile* specifies Ruby 2.0?

Comment: It wasn't but it is now, committed, pushed and still fails as before.

Comment: Can you paste or Gist your Gemfile?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rctneil/8961806

Comment: I don't mean to rush but I really could do with getting this sorted. I'm at a total roadblock and just not sure which way to go with solving this.

Comment: For those in 2013 using Rails 3x and having this issue with Heroku, updating to 3.2.22.1 and then doing bundle update will switch to raindrops .15, which does not have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've ran into the same problem: [How to install ffi on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716316/how-to-install-ffi-on-heroku)

We've tracked it down to Compass trying to install an incompatible executable (FFI) on Heroku, and it's not installing. What's so silly about this is that we don't need FFI to install on Heroku, considering it's only a development mode dependency.

Compass needs to bundle it's dependencies in a way that doesn't install unnecessary gems/executables on a production server (use `add_development_dependency`), or Heroku needs to allow it to install in the /tmp directory.

Unfortunately, we haven't solved this problem so we've reverted our code to not use the beta version of Compass and we're considering switching to Bourbon, which doesn't have unnecessary production dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for that. I managed to jiggle a few things around in my Gemfile and finally managed to get it to bundle my gems correctly on Heroku. Thanks!

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: I'd also like to know how you solved it rctneil. Please do share your solution.

Comment: Since solving it I have updated to Rails 4 but here is my latest Gemfile and this deploys with no problems: https://gist.github.com/rctneil/9163487